# CSS Animation works on one site but not personal site

Tags: css, animation

So I found this loading animation, it works on this site: http://codepen.io/Sirquini/pen/pAqeF

But when I copy the code to my computer and run it, all I get is a black dot in the top center of the screen. Why does it work on the site, but not when I copy it to my local machine?

Here is EXACTLY what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
            body {  
                background: #eee;
            }
            .loader {
                margin: 50px auto;
                text-align: center;
                position: relative;
                width: 60%;
            }
            .loader span {
                background: #222;
                border-radius: 5px;
                display: inline-block;
                position: relative;
                width: 10px;
                height: 10px;
                position: absolute;
            }
            .loader .dot_1 {
                margin-right: 10px;
                animation: loading 4s ease-in-out infinite;
            }
            .loader .dot_2 {
                animation: loading 4s ease-in-out .3s infinite;
            }
            .loader .dot_3 {
                animation: loading 4s ease-in-out .6s infinite;
            }
            @keyframes loading {
                from {
                margin-left: 50%;
                opacity: 0;
            }
            50% {
                margin-left: 0;
                opacity: 1;
            }
            to {
                margin-left: -50%;
                opacity: 0;
            }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="loader">
            <span class="dot_1"></span>
            <span class="dot_2"></span>
            <span class="dot_3"></span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The latest version of chrome. But that shouldn't matter, it works one place but not the other.

Comment: No, it shouldn't matter, but you've given us exactly nothing to work with, so I'm grasping. You're positioning .loader span twice, btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CodePen uses [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/), which is adding the [required](http://caniuse.com/css-animation) prefixed properties for this to work in Chrome.

You need this CSS:

```css
.loader .dot_1 {
    margin-right: 10px;
    -webkit-animation: loading 4s ease-in-out infinite;
            animation: loading 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.loader .dot_2 {
    -webkit-animation: loading 4s ease-in-out .3s infinite;
            animation: loading 4s ease-in-out .3s infinite;
}
.loader .dot_3 {
    -webkit-animation: loading 4s ease-in-out .6s infinite;
            animation: loading 4s ease-in-out .6s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes loading {
    from {
        margin-left: 50%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        margin-left: 0;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: -50%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes loading {
    from {
        margin-left: 50%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        margin-left: 0;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: -50%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh okay. They shouldn't automatically add that IMO.

Comment: It makes it quicker to prototype in multiple browsers, since you don't have to worry about writing the prefixed properties. However, I do agree that this is very confusing if you don't know it's happening!

Comment: Well thanks! I decided to use that js script in my project instead of writing all the prefix types.

Answer (score 0):

Pick up the zip file from codepen. You will find all dependencies in the downloaded code.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: The downloaded zip works locally. So, his problem of not working locally is solved. Secondly, he could have spotted `prefixfree.min.js` in the downloaded files and hence identified the dependency. Interestingly, though it is named "min", it actually not minified! Anyway, you had already explained the details.

Comment: Yeah, I guess. When I wrote that comment, I saw that the CSS in the .zip did not include the prefixed properties, and the only solution I considered was having those prefixed properties.